# Flask db.Column(db.Boolean) not updating for email confirmation

Tags: sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

i am trying to update a db column but it's not working for some reason, the boolean value is not changing to True. in database it is always False even when i confirm the email try token.

```
class User(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer(),primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    email = db.Column(db.String)
    password = db.Column(db.Integer)
    date_added = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    confirmed_email = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=True, default=False)

    def __init__(self,name,email,password,date_added):

        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.date_added = date_added
```

and this is my route for token

```
@app.route('/confirm_email/<token>')
def confirm_email(token):
    try:
        email = serializer.loads(token, salt='true', max_age=250)

    except SignatureExpired:
        return 'The token is expired for'

    user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
    user.confirmed_email = True
    db.session.add(user)    #<-- i tried also without this line
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Comment: `db.session.add(user)` should not be there since you are not adding a new user but updating an existing one. Are you sure there is only one record for that E-mail address since this is your criterion and you are fetching the first record found ? I also think adding a unique constraint to the email field would be wise.

Comment: @Anonymous you were right. i was trying all the time for the same email. i deleted the database and start over and now it's working for every new email. Thanks